# action of $SU(2)$

Tags: representation-theory

Let $L=\mathbb C[u,v]$ (the $\mathbb C$-algebra of polynomials over two commuting variables $u,v$. For each non negative integer $n$ let $L_n$ be the linear subspace of homogeneous polynomials of degree $n$. Clearly $\dim(L_n)=n+1$ (a basis is given by $\{u^{n-r}v^r \text{  for } r=0...n\}$

Let  $A=\left(\begin{array}{ll}
\alpha & \beta\\
-\overline{\beta} & \overline{\alpha}
\end{array}\right)$ be an element of $SU(2)$ in other words $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb C$ are complex numbers such that $|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2=1$.

Consider the group representation $D: SU(2) \to GL(L)$ given by:

$D_A: L \to L$ is given by:

$i) D_A(I)=I$

$ii)D_A(u)=\alpha u-\overline{\beta}v$

$iii) D_A(v)= \beta u + \overline{\alpha} v$

Observe that $L_n$ is $D$-stable therefore the restriction is also a representation: $D^{(n)}:SU(2)\to GL(L_n)$.

I want to prove the following proposition:

**Proposition:** $D^{(n)}$ is a unitary representation with respect to the following inner product on $L_n$.

$$ (\sum_{r=0}^{n}{c_r u^{n-r}v^r},\sum_{r=0}^{n}{d_r u^{n-r}v^r})=\sum_{r=0}^{n}{r!(n-r)!c_r\overline{d_r}}$$

Before I try to prove this, I want to understand why this inner product was so naturally defined. It is clear that the base is ortogonal, but why do these elements $r!(n-r)!$ come up? (In a natural way)